# Unable to build a custom Zepto package

Tags: zepto

I've been trying to do a custom build of Zepto (I do have coffee installed globally already), with the following commands:

```
git clone https://github.com/madrobby/zepto.git
cd zepto/
npm install
MODULES="polyfill zepto event ajax fx touch" ./make dist
```

but keep running into the problem of things hanging immediately after

```
> zepto@1.0.0 dist /Users/johnny/Development/zepto
> coffee make dist
```

With the lack of verbose build commentary from coffee, I can't tell if anything's erroring, but I can't imagine that building Zepto would take more than a few minutes (and certainly not over an hour). Even their default dist build (without customizations) hangs at the same place, and happens both on my Ubuntu and Mac boxes.

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: Never did, and just gave up doing a custom build.

Answer (score 1):

As per https://github.com/madrobby/zepto/issues/782#issuecomment-20852321 if you install coffeescript > 1.5.0 this problem should go away. You can get the latest by running:

```
sudo npm install -g coffee-script
```

I was having the same problem and bumping my version of coffeescript fixed it (i was on 1.4.0)

Comment: That fixed this problem for me. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

Replace `./make dist` with `npm run-script dist`

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with the same problem and came across this web app which generates a custom zepto build for you. All you have to do is select the modules you want included. I just used it and it worked fine:
http://github.e-sites.nl/zeptobuilder/